# Laravel: scope search by date

Tags: php, laravel, date, search, timestamp

I need to search records by creation date in Laravel

my User Model

```
public function scopeCreate_at($query, $created_at){
    if($created_at)
        return $query->whereRaw('created_at', 'LIKE', "%$created_at%");
}
```

My UserController

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request){
    $name  = $request->get('name');
    $email  = $request->get('email');
    $bio  = $request->get('bio');
    $created_at  = $request->get('created_at');

    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->name($name)
        ->email($email)
        ->bio($bio)
        ->created_at($created_at)
        ->paginate(10);
    return view('user', compact('users'));
}
```

The view

```
<div class="form-group">
{ Form::date('created_at', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Creacion'])}}
</div>
```

But, when I reload the page, I have this

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::created_at does not exist.
```

The others methods works very well

Comment: change `scopeCreate_at` to `scopeCreatedat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'created_at' !== 'create_at'`

`scopeCreate_at`

**Update:**

```
public function scopeCreate_at
```

`scopeCreate_at`

**Update:**

`...Create_at`

**Update:**

*lagbox hands the OP the letter `'d'` and says, "You dropped this"*

But seriously, you can name the function `scopeCreated_at` or call the scope by what you named it `create_at` to resolve that issue.

Comment: Change the parameters in the method, but I have the same error

Comment: It's true, I was going around and around and I could not see it. Thank you very much

Comment: happens to everyone :)